# PHPExcel save a dynamic file

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have the  following code which is supposed to save in a file server :

```
 $month_name = "MARCH2014";


       $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,"C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\{$month_name}\{$username}.xlsx",__FILE__));
```

I keep getting the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file C: mpp\htdocs    imesheetiles\{MARCH2014}\{HS0103}.xlsx.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php:399 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\controllers\time_sheet.php(6132): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('C:?mpp\htdocs?i...') #1 [internal function]: Time_sheet->save_time_sheet() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\index.php(202): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php on line 399
```

But when I use the  following :

```
   $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,"C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\MARCH2014\HS0103.xlsx",__FILE__));
```

I get no error, 
please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your replacement is necessary? Why not just use that string as your replacement replaces all of __FILE__ anyways?

Comment: Best idea allways is Debugging! Just output the filepath before using it to ->save() and check that it contains what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard PHP escape characters:

```
"C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\{$month_name}\{$username}.xlsx"
```

attempts to escape

```
\xa => character <hex 0a> (<Line feed>)
\h  => ???
\t  => <tab character>
\f  => ???
```

If you want a `\` to be `\` rather than the first character of an escaped sequence in PHP, then you need to escape it as `\\`

so

```
"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\timesheet\\files\\{$month_name}\\{$username}.xlsx"
```

The alternative is to make your directory paths "safe" by using a unix directory separator (`/`), which will still also work on Windows and Macs

```
"/xampp/htdocs/timesheet/files/{$month_name}/{$username}.xlsx"
```